# problem with MSI acpi on laptop

Tags: acpi

I have a MSI laptop, but i can't use any distribution whitout disable acpi, I would like to know if i can do something to be able to use ubuntu with MSI ACPI.

Distribution not working with acpi :

```
 Ubuntu 16
```

Comment: What model you have?

Comment: This seem to be related [to this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119831). You can try the workaround with setting `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"`, consider leaving them a comment with your model if that worked for you.

Comment: Your older question has been edited to encompass this question and also has slightly more information about the other Linux distros you tried, so I am going to dupe this question and point it to your older question.